# Windows Remote Desktop Certificate is re-created after deleting from the Remote Desktop store

Tags: certificate

I'm running a WS2019 in Hyper-V.

After deleting a certificate in the Remote Desktop Store and it returns after deleting it.

I changed Certificate Auto enrollment settings but it does not help, the certificate returns.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. Windows creates its own certificate automatically.

Comment: If this is for a report, a scheduled task may be created to automate the deletion of the certificate using certutil -delstore

Comment: If windows creates its own certificate automatically, why is it that doesn't trust it and asks to install in Trusted Store?

Comment: Windows doesn't need it in the Trusted Store.